# How do I package a python script to run on Windows?

Tags: python, package

I created a simply pyhthon script on Ubuntu which I would like to share with Windows users.

How do I package this script so that Windows user do not have to install python and extra modules to use the script?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/): it packages your script for Windows